# 404 /server Not Found - Nodejs Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

i am trying to send data from app.js to nodejs server.js but AJAX is giving error `POST http://localhost:9615/server 404 (Not Found)`

When I open `http://localhost:9615/server` on browser it work fine and show desired output that is `callback('{"msg": "OK"}')`

Here is **app.js** code

I have also tried url: 'server' and '/server'

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:9615/server',
            // dataType: "jsonp",
            data: '{"idToken": '+idToken+'}',
            type: 'POST',
            jsonpCallback: 'callback', 
            success: function (data) {
                var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                console.log('Success: '+ret.msg);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error.message);

            },
        });
```

Here is **server.js** code

```
app.get('/server', function(req,res, next){
    console.log('Request received: ');
    util.log(util.inspect(req)) 
    util.log('Request recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url) // this line logs just the method and url

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('GOT DATA!');
    });
    res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');
 });
```

Browser Screenshot:

[image]

Console Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to POST something on a GET endpoint.

Change to post

```
app.post('/server', function(req,res, next){
    console.log('Request received: ');
    util.log(util.inspect(req)) 
    util.log('Request recieved: \nmethod: ' + req.method + '\nurl: ' + req.url) // this line logs just the method and url

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('GOT DATA!');
    });
    res.end('callback(\'{\"msg\": \"OK\"}\')');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

because when you do 
'http://localhost:9615/server' in browser its a get request

& The one you are trying in code is post request.

Change either one as per your use .!